# Get owner of a file stored in server in human readable format php

Tags: php, file

I am using the function `fileowner($file)` where `$file` is the file . What I am getting the result as 33 , 0 like that. I need to get the result as `www-data`, `root` which ever be the owner.

Also I need the permission details of the file in human readable form.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

`$file` is the variable where the path of the file is stored for eg: `/path/to/abc.jpg`. I need the owner of that file in human readable form not as numbers.

Comment: Please tell us,what is in the $file ? and what do you want?

Comment: [`posix_getpwuid( fileowner($file) )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwuid.php) might be what you're after?

Comment: $file is the variable where the path of the file is stored for eg: /path/to/abc.jpg. I need the owner of that file in human readable form not as numbers. Hope the question is clear now.